# How do we unprotect a question?

Tags: support

I'm interested in answering [this question](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/2834/achilles-and-his-gold). However, after I composed my answer in an editor, I saw that the question is not answerable unless I have more reputation. I guess the idea is that I should find a less active question, then answer it, and hope someone up-votes my answer, and use that reputation to finally share the answer I really wanted to share in the first instance.

However, I'm not going to remember to do this. Is there a way that we can unprotect the question so that I can post an answer today? It is three years old, so to call it "Highly active" seems dubious. Furthermore, I thought the purpose of this site was to encourage people to share information by answering questions. When I have to get someone to vote on something I don't care about, and don't know about - just to earn the privilege to show them and let them vote on something I do care about, and do (think I) know about - it seems a betrayal of the democratic philosophy of the site. I shouldn't have to be an office-holder to run for office, in other words.

Any tips? It looks like the OP wants the question unprotected but doesn't have the right to make it so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Users with sufficient reputation can unprotect a question. After some consideration, I have decided to do so in this case, however:

> It is three years old, so to call it "Highly active" seems dubious.

To the contrary, popular questions are usually the ones people find on Google and then try to "answer" with a comment or follow up questions. That's a big part of why this mechanism exists.